# Can I make the lines thicker on this brushstroke animation I made with an svg in html & css?

Tags: python, html, css, django, svg

I made a svg and animated it to write out my text. I want it to have thick brushstrokes and look similar to this website(http://weaintplastic.com), writing out letters one by one. At the moment it just traces the letters at the same time making it hard to read the word and the lines are very thin. I would like to make the brushstrokes thicker and to animate each letter to write out one at a time with html and css.

I created my svg on this website(https://vectr.com/) by using their text function and then sketched the path of each individual letter with the trace tracing each individual letter with the pen tool.
I used this link to open the svg https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ and copied the svg as text. Then I followed the instructions on this website to animate it https://dev.to/oppnheimer/you-too-can-animate-svg-line-animation-jgm.

Here's the link to my code
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgEadZ#anon-signup

html with svg path

```
 <div id="header">
        <div id="content">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="640" height="640">
      <defs>
        <path d="M189.37 447.93l-8.06-17.6-18.94-41.4-17.9 41.76-9.1 21.24" id="a"/>
        <path d="M259.91 434.47l-.15 7.99-12.14 7.78-26-.48-13.85-8.26-5.63-19.61 12.49-26.27 24.08-4.55 18.82 10.35" id="b"/>
        <path d="M332.37 436.93l-20 15-20-4-9-11-5-13 5-25 13-10H320l12.37 10" id="c"/>
        <path d="M402.37 451.93h-47v-63h43" id="d"/>
        <path d="M398.37 418.43h-43" id="e"/>
        <path d="M470.46 388.93v61h-7.15l-42.94-61v61" id="f"/>
        <path d="M538.17 388.93h-53 25v63" id="g"/>
        <path d="M181.54 428.33h-38.46" id="h"/>
      </defs>
      <use xlink:href="#a" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000"/>
      <use xlink:href="#b" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000"/>
      <use xlink:href="#c" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000"/>
      <use xlink:href="#d" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000"/>
      <use xlink:href="#e" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000"/>
      <use xlink:href="#f" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000"/>
      <use xlink:href="#g" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000"/>
      <use xlink:href="#h" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000"/>
    </svg>
    </div>
    </div>

css with strokes
     svg {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background-color: #ebedf5;
      }
      path {
        stroke-dasharray: 100;
        animation: draw 5s;
        background-color: white;
      }

      @keyframes draw {
        from {
          stroke-dashoffset: 0
        }
        to {
          stroke-dashoffset: 100;
        }
      }
```

I think why the brushstrokes are so thin is because i am using the pen tool to trace my logo. I would like the brushstrokes to be thicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked the CodePen linked to the website and it seems like there is a css property `stroke-width` to modify the width/thickness of the stroke.

**CSS**

```
path {
  stroke-width: 20;
}
```

**Code from article's example:**

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

svg {
 height: 90vh;
 width: 100vw;
 background-color: PaleGreen;
 padding: 5vh;
}

path {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 20;
}

.v1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 200;
  animation: draw 1s infinite;
}

.v2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 10;
  stroke-dashoffset: 200;
  animation: draw 2s alternate infinite;
}

.v3 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1200 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2700;
  animation: draw 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="184.64 83.41 389.16 433.07">
  <defs>
    <path d="M200.05 429.61c26.29 30.73 55.8 52.8 88.53 66.21a265.15 265.15 0 0 0 55.9 15.84 127.39 127.39 0 0 0 91.74-19.28c21.76-14.38 36.06-29.03 42.92-43.96 18.8-40.95 16.55-89.29 10.21-119.89-6.34-30.61-8.47-85.69-20.16-119.84-7.78-22.77-24.58-34.58-50.4-35.45l11.34-69.28a1.2 1.2 0 0 1 1.43-.99l20.12 4a6.8 6.8 0 0 1 3.57 1.96l20.58 21.58a25.43 25.43 0 0 1 6.7 21.55l-1.31 8.19a34.66 34.66 0 0 0 4.98 24.09l47.79 75.12a23.65 23.65 0 0 1 2.98 18.47l-4.44 17.66c20.46-13.28 32.54-29.01 36.25-47.18 3.01-14.74 2.67-52.06-1.03-111.96a46.34 46.34 0 0 0-24.68-38.16l-23.01-12.12a15.34 15.34 0 0 0-13.66-.3l-42.72 20.1-33.08-7.96a.35.35 0 0 1-.26-.34v-1.01a3.18 3.18 0 0 0-2.98-3.17l-8.43-.53a4.58 4.58 0 0 0-4.84 5.03l3.84 37.76a32.76 32.76 0 0 1-2.6 16.44l-6.66 15.17 6.33 7.79c13.17 2.89 21.9 9.75 26.2 20.56 6.46 16.23 1.08 54.58 1.94 72.35 1.79 37.1-1.78 16.01 3.37 60.47 5.15 44.45-12.16 85.67-31.51 110.6-19.34 24.92-49.78 50.64-75.86 54.01-40.13 5.19-66.8-13.56-80-56.26-29.35 7.44-49.72 3.08-61.13-13.09-17.1-24.26-18.66-74.4 9.35-125.9 28.01-51.5 96.91-70.78 102.69-80.1 5.77-9.33 20.22-32.88 40.91-46.97 20.68-14.09 38.51-13.74 46.54-9.4 5.35 2.9 10.46 7.47 15.32 13.73l-65.5 124.46c-8.71 13.78-14.51 25.51-17.42 35.18-4.35 14.5-5.36 21.73 0 22.83 5.36 1.09 9.29-8.43 11.21-13.39 1.91-4.96 1.91-29.23-1.97-30.08-3.89-.84-15.5-.59-26.85 6.64-11.34 7.22-12.04 18.67-10.23 23.44 1.82 4.78 10.77-.82 17.94-9.44 4.78-5.75 8.08-11.73 9.9-17.94" id="a"/>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#a" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" class="v1"/>
</svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="184.64 83.41 389.16 433.07">
  <use xlink:href="#a" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" class="v2"/>
</svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="184.64 83.41 389.16 433.07">
  <use xlink:href="#a" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" class="v3"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Oh I must have missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Besides the `stroke-width` (used to change the stroke width) there are other problems with your code. You are using `stroke-dasharray: 100;` and `stroke-dashoffset: 100;` but this won't do since every letter have a different path length. In the next example I've putted the total length of each path in a css variable to be used by the animation.

Also your paths are drawn backwards: If you need your animation to run from right to left you need to animate the path from `stroke-dashoffset: calc(var(--len) * -1);` to 0.

I hope it helps.

```css
svg {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #ebedf5;
  }
  path {
    stroke-dasharray: var(--len);
    stroke-dashoffset: calc(var(--len) * -1);
    animation: draw 5s forwards;
    background-color: white;
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:3px;
  }
  
  @keyframes draw {
    to {
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="content">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="100 385 500 100">

    <path d="M189.37 447.93l-8.06-17.6-18.94-41.4-17.9 41.76-9.1 21.24" id="a" style="--len:133.43"/>
    <path d="M259.91 434.47l-.15 7.99-12.14 7.78-26-.48-13.85-8.26-5.63-19.61 12.49-26.27 24.08-4.55 18.82 10.35" id="b" style="--len:160.01"/>
    <path d="M332.37 436.93l-20 15-20-4-9-11-5-13 5-25 13-10H320l12.37 10" id="c" style="--len:154.97"/>
    <path d="M402.37 451.93h-47v-63h43" id="d" style="--len:153"/>
    <path d="M398.37 418.43h-43" id="e" style="--len:43"/>
    <path d="M470.46 388.93v61h-7.15l-42.94-61v61" id="f" style="--len:203.75"/>
    <path d="M538.17 388.93h-53 25v63" id="g" style="--len:141"/>
    <path d="M181.54 428.33h-38.46" id="h" style="--len:38.46"/>

</svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Especially liked the use of variables to store the length of the path

Comment: Thanks I feel like I have a better understanding of this concept now

Answer (score 1):

Since any font in `SVG` becomes a graphic object, rather, each of its characters.

Therefore, you can animate each character's drawing without converting it to `path`

- animation CSS

```css
svg {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #ebedf5;
  }
  .txt1 {
  font-size:60px;
  fill:none;
  stroke:black;
  stroke-dashoffset:400;
  stroke-dasharray:400;
  animation: an_text 10s  forwards;
  }
  @keyframes an_text {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="content">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 500 100">
          
     <text class="txt1" dy="50"  shape-rendering="crispEdges">Account </text>
            
 </svg> 
  </div>
  </div>
```

- Or animation SMIL

```css
svg {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #ebedf5;
  }
  .txt1 {
  font-size:60px;
  fill:none;
  stroke:#474747;
  stroke-dashoffset:400;
  stroke-dasharray:400;
  stroke-width:1px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="content">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 500 100">
          
     <text class="txt1" dy="50" shape-rendering="crispEdges">ACCENT
        <animate
   dur="8s"
   repeatCount="1"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   values="400;0;400"
     repeatCount="1" />
    </text>
            
 </svg> 
  </div>
  </div>
```

- Another animation example

The `textPath` command is used.

```css
svg {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #ebedf5;
  }
  .txt1 {
  font-size:80px;
  fill:none;
  stroke:black;
  shape-rendering:crispEdges;
  }
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="content">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="100 385 500 100">
       <defs>
    <path id="animatedLine" >
        <animate attributeName="d" from="m200,335 h0" to="m200,335 h400" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </path>
     </defs>
      <text class="txt1" dy="100">
      <textPath xlink:href="#animatedLine">
        ACCENT
 </textPath>
    </text>
  
 </svg>
 </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I like very much the first example where you are using SMIL to animate the text! Excelent!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS code:

```
path {
    stroke-width: 5;
}
```